# Ubuntu 20.04 freezs with Lenovo Thinkpad t14

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad

I have looked at the logs and seeing this:
[image]

If I'm understanding this, does the system tries to Swap to crypto swap file?
My HDD is encrypted and I set up a regular swap file...

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=ebdb51fe-2271-4425-951a-825066ef4e7b /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=0441-297F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

I just got another random freeze (7 days after the first one) which I had to reset my laptop for, with the following logs:

```
18:52:30 kernel: sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
18:52:30 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
18:52:20 wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to create a P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3
18:52:20 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
18:52:19 systemd: Failed to start Cryptography Setup for cryptswap.
18:52:19 systemd-cryptse: crypt_init() failed: Block device required
18:52:19 kernel: sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
18:52:19 systemd: Failed to start Cryptography Setup for cryptswap.
18:52:19 systemd-cryptse: crypt_init() failed: Block device required
18:52:18 systemd: Failed to start Cryptography Setup for cryptswap.
18:52:18 systemd-cryptse: crypt_init() failed: Block device required
18:52:18 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.HIDD._DSM due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE) (20190816/psparse-529)
18:52:18 kernel: crypt_init() failed: Block device required
18:52:18 kernel: Device /cryptswap doesn't exist or access denied.
18:52:18 kernel: Failed to start Cryptography Setup for cryptswap.
18:52:18 kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=ebdb51fe-2271-4425-951a-825066ef4e7b /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=0441-297F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Adding /etc/crypttab:

```
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID=bca86e55-cc12-4b54-ba1e-61856cc8db55 none luks,discard
cryptswap /cryptswap /dev/urandom swap
```

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/fstab` to your question as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my swapped is not encrypted I removed the following line:

cryptswap /cryptswap /dev/urandom swap
from the /etc/crypttab file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

line from `/etc/fstab`. It sets up an encrypted swap that probably doesn't exist.

Comment: do you know why it's doing this randomly? or at least it feels random...